# Sub-string splitting with php

Tags: php, string, split

I have a string 33#math#indonesia#Primary 2, and want to be separated into like this 33,math,indonesia,primary 2 into four parts
[image]

Comment: $stringParts = explode('#','33#math#indonesia#Primary 2'); this will return string parts into array seperated with #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$array = explode('#',$string);
print_r($array);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/uCPY0

if you want to add `,` instead of `#` then use [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
echo $string = str_replace('#',',',$string);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/8Mm08

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace the `#` with `,`

Answer (score 1):

> Use can also use implode and explode

```
$a = '33#math#indonesia#Primary 2';
$b = explode('#', $a);
$c = implode(',', $b);
print_r($c);
```

> 33,math,indonesia,Primary 2